# Twitter Typeahead - Dynamically Specify Search Properties

Tags: twitter-typeahead

I've searched and searched, but I must not be asking the right question.  I'm working with [Twitter's typeahead](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) and I've run into a bit of a snag.  I'm prefetching the typeahead dataset, which looks like this:

Dataset: myData.json:

```
[{
   id: 1,
   name: "Some Name"
},
{
   id: 2,
   name: "Some Other Name"
}]
```

Right now, the valueKey property is set to search by 'name'

```
$(myField).typeahead({
   name     : "myFieldName",
   valueKey : "name",
   prefetch : 'myUrl/myData.json',
});
```

Everything works great - the user types the name into a textbox, and the results come back.  However, I'd also like them to be able to search by ID.  Is there any way to do this?  What I'd ultimately like to be able to do is issue two explicit queries (one that matches on name, one that matches on ID) at will so that I have greater control over the results (there are instances in our app where all we have is an ID to go on)..

Thanks!